# Redirecionar google chrome para localhost quando offline

Tags: google-chrome, bash, linux, chromium

Tenho um sistema em cima de um raspberry que precisa trabalhar online. Um raspberry que abre diretamente uma pagina no Chromium. O que estou tentando fazer é o seguinte com este scprit que fiz.

```
#!/bin/bash

wget -q --spider https://v4.permitt.com.br
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
if [ -e /home/condoseg/offline ]; then
sudo rm -rf /home/condoseg/offline
killall chromium-browser-v7
DISPLAY=:0 chromium-browser --args --incognito --disable-web-security --kiosk --allow-running-insecure-content --user-data-dir="/home/condoseg" --use-fake-ui-for-media-stream https://v4.permitt.com.br &
fi
else
if [ ! -e /home/condoseg/offline ]; then
killall chromium-browser
DISPLAY=:0 chromium-browser --args --incognito --disable-web-security --kiosk --allow-running-insecure-content --use-fake-ui-for-media-stream --user-data-dir="/home/condoseg" http://localhost/novoindex.html &
touch /home/condoseg/offline
fi
fi
```

Ele identifica quando o computador tem acesso a internet, e que quando esteja sem, redireciona para um pagina no localhost. E vice versa. Eu ja consegui fazer para quando estiver offline ele redirecione para a pagina que eu criei dentro do localhost, porém quando o computador volta a ter internet, eu gostaria que ele voltasse para a página inicial do sistema.

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que faltou apenas um pouco de lógica no seu script, pois ele faz o teste apenas uma vez. Coloque dentro de um laço com uma condição verdadeira para continuar verificando infinitamente.

Exemplo para rodar a cada 3 minutos:

```
while :
do
   seu script
done
sleep 180
```